# The fiber of the sheaf of differentials is indeed the Zariski cotangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I started studying differentials on schemes (Hartshorne II.8), and read Eisenbud to gain more intuition and algebra. After vaguely understanding cotangent bundle and conormal sequence, I tried to calculate fiber of $\Omega_{S/k}$, which I expected to be the cotangent space $m/m^2$.

Let $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_r]/I$ where $I=(f_1,\dots, f_s)$. Using the technique in Eisenbud, $\Omega_{S/k}=\text{coker } J = \oplus Sdx_i/\text{im } J$ when $J: \oplus Sde\to \oplus Sdx_i$ is the map between free modules given by the matrix $(\partial f_j/\partial x_i)$.

I thought the natural map would be $\oplus S_m dx_i\to m=(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_r-a_r)$ sending $dx_i \mapsto x_i-a_i$. Now, we have $\sum \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} dx_i \in\text{im }J$, and it maps to $\sum \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} (x_i-a_i)$, which is a hyperplane analytically tangent to variety at $m$.

But I can't show this is algebraically tangent to the variety, or $\sum \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} (x_i-a_i)\in m^2$. My question is: Am I missing something trivial? Or this is a point of Jacobian criterion? (In latter case, I guess I should use conormal sequence and so on.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the (purely algebraic) Taylor expansion on $f_j$ so that $f_j = \sum \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(x_i-a_i) + \sum\frac{\partial^2 f_j}{\partial x_k \partial x_l} (x_k-a_k)(x_l-a_l) + \cdots$. Then obviously $f_j - \sum \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(x_i-a_i) \in m^2$. Note that $f_j = 0$ in $S$.